# What is a Long lived TCP/IP Connection?

Tags: networking

What is a long lived TCP/IP Connection? Does this has anything to do with keepalives?

I understand, that TCP creates a connection and makes sure that for example a HTTP Packet is send to a (web)server. I came across the term long lived TCP/IP Connection. What exactly does it mean?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A "long-lived TCP/IP connection" is one that is kept open for longer than necessary to perform a single transaction or operation. Any TCP connection kept open for more than a few minutes is generally considered a long-lived TCP/IP connection.

Comment: How is it held open?

Comment: @David Simply by not being closed by either end.